# How do I use a StyledComponent where React.Component is expected?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to create a typescript React app that and have run into an issue when using `styled-components`. Below is a rough idea of what I'm attempting:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export type MyProps = {
  wrapper?: React.Component,
};

const DefaultWrapper = styled.div`
  background: blue;
`;

const MyComponent = ({wrapper: Wrapper = DefaultWrapper}: MyProps) => {
  return <Wrapper className='my-wrapper'>
    Some child content
  </Wrapper>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

My issue comes when I try to render `MyComponent` within another component as it throws an error saying `JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures`.

I'd like some way that I could use a styled component as either the default value or as a valid value for the `wrapper` prop in such a way as to not expose that I'm using styled components internally. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

`React.Component` is a React class element (not a type), instead, use the type `React.ComponentType<any>`. If you're working with component type constraints and expect `wrapper` to be certain type of component, then swap out the `React.ComponentType<any>` with the necessary constraint(s) -- like `React.ComponentClass<any, any>` for class-based components or `React.FC<any>` for functional components.

#### Solution

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export type MyProps = {
  wrapper?: React.ComponentType<any>;
};

const DefaultWrapper = styled.div`
  background: blue;
`;

const MyComponent = ({ wrapper: Wrapper = DefaultWrapper }: MyProps) => {
  return <Wrapper className="my-wrapper">Some child content</Wrapper>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

#### Working repo

Ignore the `'React' was used before it was defined.` eslint warning, it's a codesandbox issue -- works fine locally:

[image: Edit Typescript - Defaults]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I thought I'd just have the incorrect type somewhere, but didn't know where to look for my error.